# How to get the maximum value in case of tie while trying to find the mode for numerical columns

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to calculate the mode of a numerical column in a groupby but I'm getting ties.
How do I get the maximum value among the tied values in this case
Code that I'm using right now

Data, code and output so far

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'client_id':['A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'C'],
    'date':['2019-01-01', '2019-01-01', '2019-01-01', '2019-01-01', '2019-01-01', '2019-01-01', '2019-01-01', '2019-01-01'],
    'value':['2', '2', '1', '1', '3', '3', '1', np.NaN]
})


df.groupby(['client_id', 'date']).agg(pd.Series.mode).reset_index()
```

OUTPUT -

[image: OUTPUT]

The desirable output for mode for the first row should be 2

Answer (score 0):

[`Series.mode`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.mode.html) returns a Series, you can get the max of it with [`Series.max`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.max.html)

```py
df['value'] = pd.to_numeric(df['value'], errors='coerce')
out = (df.groupby(['client_id', 'date'])['value']
       .agg(lambda col: col.mode().max())
       .reset_index())
```

```
print(out)

  client_id        date  value
0         A  2019-01-01    2.0
1         B  2019-01-01    3.0
2         C  2019-01-01    NaN
```